# Pass DOM element to iScroll function scrollToElement with eq

Tags: jquery, iscroll

I am using the scrollToElement feature of [iScroll](http://iscrolljs.com/#indicators) to automatically scroll to an element. All I should have to do is "pass an element or a selector" (according to the docs), and this has worked for me before. In this more complex example, however:

```
$('div.entry-content > ul li a').on('click', function(){
    var numClicked=$(this).parent('li').index();
    $('h2:eq('+numClicked+')').css('color','#f00');
    scroller.scrollToElement($('h2:eq('+numClicked+')'), 1000);
});
```

...I am getting an error message. The CSS statement is working, so the H2 along with the EQ is getting to the right element. But when I try to pass the same thing to scrollToElement, it doesn't work. Is there a better way for me to reference the element?

Comment: What error are you getting?  Have you logged "scroller" to the console to make sure it is defined at the point that the function executes?

Comment: Error message is "SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified". Yes, if I just put 'h2' as the element/selector, then it works. It apparently doesn't want to do any jQuery selector calculations?

Comment: Oh, I was thinking you were saying that the css setting was working, but the scroller part was not.  Hmm.  Have you tried breaking it apart?  $('h2').eq(numClicked) ?  Also console log the numClicked to see what it's value is at use time.

Comment: Since I could select the element with jQuery but iScroll would not accept the same series of selectors, I solved this by assigning a temporary class to the target, and then scrolling to the element with that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iScroll would not accept the :eq part of my selector. So, I solved this by using jQuery to add a temporary class to the element using :eq, then passing the class to iScroll. Now it works fine.